# Join 2 tables by merk_id

Tags: php, join, distinct

I'm trying to combine to tables. I got 11 different brands and I got wheels that belong to a brand. You can select a brand by its name with an option selectbox and when submut I want alle the wheels with that brand.

This is the class I'm using:

```
 <?php

include_once "connect.class.php";

class merken extends connect
{   
    private $merkenlijst;


    public function getMerken($database, $id = NULL)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$database."_merken";
        if(!empty($id))
        {
            $sql .= " WHERE merk_code=:id"; 
        }
        else
        {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY merk_naam ASC";
        }
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            if(!empty($id)){ $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR); }
            $stmt->execute();
            $this->merkenlijst = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $stmt->closeCursor();

            return $this->merkenlijst;
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die ( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }


    public function __construct($dbo = NULL)
    {

        parent::__construct($dbo);
    }
}

?>
```

This is how I echo the info from my database:

```
                        <div class="bandwielkolom">
                        <form action="index.php?lang=nl&amp;p=<?php echo $_GET['p']; ?>#keuze" method="post">
                            <table class="bandentabel">
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="2">Zoek op merk<a name="wiel"></a></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Merk:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="wiel_merk">
                                            <option value="0">- Merk -</option>
<?php
    $merken = $merkclass->getMerken($website);
    foreach($merken as $merk)
    {
        echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<option value=\"".$merk->merk_code."\"";
        if(isset($_GET['search']) && $_GET['search'] == "wiel" && isset($_GET['merk']) && $_GET['merk'] == $merk->merk_code || isset($_POST['wiel_submit']) && $_POST['wiel_merk'] == $merk->merk_code) { echo " selected=\"selected\""; }
        echo ">".$merk->merk_naam."</option>\n";
    }
?>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" name="wiel_submit" value="Zoek" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearboth"></div>
                    <br />
<?php
if(isset($_POST['wiel_submit']) && $_POST['wiel_submit'] == "Zoek" || isset($_GET['merk']))
{
    $merk = NULL;
    if(isset($_POST['wiel_submit']) && $_POST['wiel_submit'] == "Zoek")
    {
        $merk = $_POST['wiel_merk'];
    }
    $merken = $merkclass->getMerken($website, $merk);
        foreach($merken as $merk)
    {
?>
                    <img src="http://www.etyre.net/preview/bnet/logos/<?php echo str_replace(".png", "_150.png", $merk->merk_logo); ?>" width="150" class="logo" alt="<?php echo $merk->merk_naam; ?>"/>
                    <div id="merken">
                    <li><span class="title"><?php echo $merk->wiel_info; ?></span>
                            <a href="http://www.inter-tyre.nl/inter-tyre/images/w3/<?php echo $merk->wiel_foto; ?>" class="preview" title="Fotonummer: <?php echo $merk->wiel_foto;  ?>">
                                <img src="http://www.inter-tyre.nl/inter-tyre/images/w2/<?php echo $merk->wiel_foto; ?>" alt="Fotonummer: <?php echo $merk->wiel_foto; ?>" class="wheelImg"/>
                            </a>
                        <div class="clearboth"></div>
                    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
<?php
}
?>
```

How can I join this two tables together so than when I select a brand it does show all the wheels that has that brand? And no double brands in my select option?

[wielen table](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/822/wielen.png/)

[merken table](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/717/merken.png/)
Can somebody help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, and it appears to me that you are too lazy to just go and read the documentation for [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Anyway, something along the following lines should work:

```
SELECT w.*,m.* FROM wielen w
LEFT JOIN merken m ON w.merk_id = m.id
WHERE m.id = $your_current_merk;
```

This gives you a list of all wheels, together with their associated brand information.

If you want to do it the other way around and you don't want to have your brands reoccurring, with your current setup, you would want to do a GROUP_CONCAT, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447631/subqueries-for-each-result-or-inner-join-with-php-loop-or/11447897#11447897).

Comment: I did read it but I did not write this php script and I'm a bit new to php so dont know how to realise it... I also tried distinct to get rid of my double selectfields but that did not work either... The code you just gave to me... How can I use this in the Class I just posted?